# How to plot log normalized image using imshow () (matplotlib)?

Tags: image, numpy, matplotlib, normalize

I understand the concept. But I think I am making a silly mistake. This is what I want (psuedo-ish code). This is for an exercise. I am unable to understand lower origin part and the syntax of the first two lines.

```
norm = LogNorm(image.mean() + 0.5 * image.std(), image.max(), clip='True', 
               cmap=cm.gray, origin="lower")
```

`image` is a numpy array here. How to pass these `norm` and `cmap` parameters in matplotlib to `plt.show` or `imshow()`?

This doesn't work:

```
imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray, LogNorm(......))
```

Comment: what is `lm`? Where are you calculating the center of mass?

Comment: Perhaps `lm` is a typo for `ln`, the natural log?

Comment: @tcaswell My guess is `lm` should be [`LogNorm`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)?

Comment: I think the real mystery here is how the title relates to the question.

Comment: Haha, sorry for the trouble. Mixed up two questions. Was groggy at the time of asking. 'lm' was given in the assignment. It is a typo, I guess as well for ln/LogNorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
from matplotlib import colors, cm, pyplot as plt

norm = colors.LogNorm(image.mean() + 0.5 * image.std(), image.max(), clip='True')
plt.imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray, norm=norm, origin="lower")
```

This creates a special colormap that ranges from `image.mean() + 0.5 * image.std()` to `image.max()` using a logarithmic scale. More general information is here: [`colors`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) and specifically: [`LogNorm`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm)

The `origin='lower'` means that the `[0,0]` element (the 'origin') of the array is shown in the lower left part of the figure.  Normally the origin of an array is in the upper left.